# Visual build pro - Perforce integration and variable assignation

Tags: perforce

We use Visual build pro and we would like to get some variable from a perforce command.

We have a step which is a perforce one, with the global options set up (Client and Port) and we would like to get the workspace location (local) of the remote depot location (variable is P4_ASSET_DIR).

The command is set to "where" and is done on a specific location of the depot.

We get the right variable but we are unable to determine how it is assigned to the right value ("ASSET_DIR").

Answer (score 0):

While writing this question I found the solution ^^

if you edit the Step and click on Script Editor+, on the Step tab there is a small script.

```
Sub vbld_StepDone()
AssignLastLocalP4ToMacro("ASSET_DIR")
End Sub
```

:)